# fodPollResults (FORTIFY on demand) plugin is not working properly either in direct plugin or pipeline script mode in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fortify

We are using "fortify on-demand (FOD)" platform to scan our source code to find out any security vulnerabilities are present. We integrated the FOD with jenkins to automate the process of uploading and scanning. And we opted the pipeline script method for integration. All the process up to uploading and scanning is running fine and we are capturing policy scan status (passed or failed) also, but the pipeline script of **fodPollResults** is failing to fail the build when the FOD policy scan is failed. irrespective of the result of policy scan the build is getting success.

**jenkins pipeline script**

```
stage('FOD POLL') {
    steps {
           fodPollResults bsiToken: '', personalAccessToken: 'fortify_personal_access_token', policyFailureBuildResultPreference: 2, pollingInterval: 3, releaseId: '******', tenantId: '', username: ''
    }
}
```

[Fortify on Demand Poll Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjWhz.png)

Answer (score 1):

the source code of this plugin is located here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/fortify-on-demand-uploader-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/fodupload/steps/FortifyPollResults.java

and there is a bug ticket about this problem here:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/fortify-on-demand-uploader-plugin/issues/118

Following workaround seems to work:

```
steps {
   fodPollResults ...
   script {
     if (manager.logContains('.*Scan failed established policy check.*')) {
       error("Build failed because of negative fortify policy check.")  
     }
   }
}
```